# Python list problem

Tags: python

I am having a problem with python lists. The simplified version is:

```
mylist1 = [...some items in a list...]

mylist2 = mylist1

mylist1.pop(i)

mylist.insert(i,item)

print(mylist1)

print(mylist2)
```

the problem is that I want mylist2 to remain the original version of mylist1. Is there any workaround of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
mylist2 = mylist1[:]
```

instead of

```
mylist2 = mylist1
```

This is a standard idiom for making a copy of a list.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of assigning `mylist2` to `mylist1`, you need to make a copy of it. This can be done by using the `list` constructor:

```
mylist2 = list(mylist)
```

Or through [`copy.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.copy) (or [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)):

```
import copy
mylist2 = copy.copy(mylist)
```

The `copy` module can be used to copy other objects (eg: `dict`s) and make deep copies.
See this wiki page on the [difference between a shallow and a deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_vs._Shallow_vs._Lazy_copy).

Finally there's the slice syntax:

```
mylist2 = mylist[:]
```

But I *personally* avoid using this rather cryptic syntax for the reasons listed [here](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list).

Comment: What's with the downvote? Is it because of the comment on the slice syntax? I posted a link with reasons why you shouldn't do it. It's also ugly, cryptic and frankly unpythonic.

Comment: And FWIW Alex Martelli [agrees with me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601269/python-how-to-make-a-completely-unshared-copy-of-a-complicated-list-deep-copy/1601334#1601334).

Comment: `[:]` does exactly what you expect once you understood slices, so I wouldn't call it cryptic. I'd rather avoid obsessing over these forms, it's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Jochen I agree that it boils down to personal preference, and I stated that I *personally* avoid doing that. But you still can't use `[:]` to copy unsubscriptable types like generators.

Comment: you are not copying the generator, you are converting it in a different object type (a list). You can also apply list() to a dictionary. At least slicing gives an error. I do not feel slicing is cryptic at all. Contrarily it gives me a more clear feeling of being copying a list than list(myobject) that actually produces list from different object types, either a dict, list, set, etc

Comment: It's cryptic if you're new to Python.

Comment: @joaquin But that's the point: I don't want it to give me an error if I apply `list()` to a dictionary if I am well aware of what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
mylist2 = mylist1[:]
```

or [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) library for more complex cases where you need shallow ( `copy.copy(x)`) or deep copies (`copy.deepcopy(x)`) of your object

Note that a simple copy doesn't work for list of lists:

```
>> x =[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>> import copy
>> y = copy.copy(x)
>> y
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>> x[1][1]= 'oo'
>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 'oo', 6]]
>> y
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 'oo', 6]]
```

**Edit:**
from Mark Lutz's Learning Python 4 ed, p.150:

> There are a variety of ways to copy a list, including using the
>   built-in list function and the standard library copy module. **Perhaps
>   the most common way is to slice from start to finish**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a shallow copy of `mylist1`.

```
mylist2 = mylist1[:]
```

See [this blog post](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/11/how-to-copy-python-lists-or-other/) for more details.

However, if you list contains other lists or objects and you wish to recursively copy those too, you will need to do a [deep copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead.

```
from copy import deepcopy
mylist2 = deepcopy(mylist)
```

---

#### Footnote

I don't see why ALL answers that mention the standard`mylist[:]` idiom (see 3rd paragraph in the [introduction to List](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html)) got downvoted.

For what its worth, using the slice notation for copying  seems to be the fastest method (on my version of Python anyway. YMMV).

```
[me@home]$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
[me@home]$ python -m timeit "L1 = range(100000)" "L2 = L1[:]"
100 loops, best of 3: 3 msec per loop
[me@home]$ python -m timeit "L1 = range(100000)" "L2 = list(L1)"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.86 msec per loop
[me@home]$ python -m timeit "from copy import copy; L1 = range(100000)" "L2 = copy(L1)"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.95 msec per loop
```

That said, I do agree that `list(mylist)` is more beginner friendly than `mylist[:]`. However, both are valid and are used in the wild and I don't see why beginners should be insulated from one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the shallow copy/deep copy of python. Also known as, pointers.

This happens because lists are pointers to a data structure.  So if we have memory like this:

```
1    2    3    4    5
A    B    C    D    E
```

So, if we have a pointer with the value `1` we would get `A` if we dereference it. Now, if we copy the value in our pointer, we would get `1` not `A`, because we didn't get the *value it pointed to* and our new variable will point to the same memory space as the old one.

We either need to use the deep copy library, or the standard python idiom `mylist2 = mylist1[:]` to get a *copy of the contents* instead of copying the memory address that actually resides in mylist1.

Answer (score 0):

we can use a loop to create the  new list then we can change the list of the second element:

```
mylist1=[......]
mylist2=[]
for i in mylist1:
mylist2+[i]

mylist1.pop(..)
mylist1.insert(....,...)
print(mylist1)
print(mylist2)
```