# Python 3 list unexpected work during copy

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've got a problem with list in Python3:

I'm trying to copy data from one list to another, but this changes data in parent list

Here is this fragment:

```
for i in list(range(size)):
    j=0
    for j in list(range(size)): 
        k=newKeyOrdV[j]
        print(str(matrix))
        finalMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][newKeyOrdV[j]]
        print("MAGIC")
        print(str(matrix))
        print()
```

And it gives next output at the beginning:

> [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
>
> MAGIC
>
> [['c', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]

Later it changes and second line in it.

I tried to get data from `matrix` list in temp variable, made a copy of this list in another variable and tried to take data from it, but it changed `matrix` anyway.

Code with output may be found [here](http://ideone.com/JuqSwy).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python list problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391506/python-list-problem)

Comment: I love the originality of `list(range(size))`.

Comment: About duplicate: I tried to copy with [:] method, but I prefer list() copy method. Both of them don't solve problem

Comment: You need to copy with deepcopy because [:] and list() both do shallow copies.

Comment: `for i in list(range(size))` is sooo wrong I can't begin to express my horror! Why should you ever want to expand an iterator you're only iterating over to a list?

Comment: To mata: Well, I really sorry for it, but it just a way I used after Python 2, where I used "for i in range(number):" way. I would really appreciate if you show how it is good to be done.

Comment: just use `for i in range(size)`. there is absolutely no point in converting the range to a list before.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll keep it mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting finalMatrix = emptyMatrix and matrix = emptyMatrix, so when you change one, it changes the other.

Write `import copy` and copy the matrices using deepcopy. You only need to do it on the first one to see the change but you should do it to both.

If you do a `shallow` copy of a list, you copy it as references (basically as address/pointers in C) so the change of one list will affect the other. If you do a `deep` copy, you actually copy the elements in the list rather than the references to each element, so it is a separate/individual list that can be changed without affecting the list it was deep copied from.

Change these two lines in your code:

```
matrix = copy.deepcopy(emptyMatrix) 
finalMatrix = copy.deepcopy(emptyMatrix)
```

---

Full code:

http://ideone.com/ngItny

Comment: Isn't list(emptyMatrix) solves copy problem? It did worked it Python 2.7 as far as I remember.