# Python: swap list elements in a copied list without affecting the original list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list `a` and a list `b` which is (should be) a copy of list `a`.

```
a = [[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]]
b = a[:][:]
b[0][1], b[0][2] = b[0][2], b[0][1]
```

If I now look at `a` and `b` I get the following:

```
a = [[['a'], ['c'], ['b']], [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]]
b = [[['a'], ['c'], ['b']], [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]]
```

Why does the swap in list `b` also affects the original list `a`?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1601269/589206

Comment: I suppose `b = a[:][:]` could be written as `b = a[:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b = a[:][:]` is just `b = (a[:])[:]` or a copy of a copy of the original list. The lists inside the original list are still referenced and when you change them it shows in both lists.

You can do

```
b = [l[:] for l in a] # a new list, consisting of copies each sublist
```

or

```
from copy import deepcopy
b = deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

a = [[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b[0][1], b[0][2] = b[0][2], b[0][1]
print a, b
```