# How can I swap rows in a matrix in python without using numpy?

Tags: python, matrix

If i have the matrix:

```
[[1,1,1],[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[7,1,2]]
```

I want to swap rows 1 and 2 so that it returns:

```
[[1,1,1],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[7,1,2]]
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923521/python-swap-list-elements-in-a-copied-list-without-affecting-the-original-list

Comment: I would do it exactly the same way as **with** numpy.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this the same way you do any other swap in python:

i.e. `a, b = b, a` -- or in your case:

```
>>> matrix = [[1,1,1],[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[7,1,2]]
>>> matrix[1], matrix[2] = matrix[2], matrix[1]
>>> matrix
[[1, 1, 1], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4], [7, 1, 2]]
```