# Multiple 2D list confusion in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python programme which can animate within a text console, however I'm having this problem where one list is supposed to be kept blank and the other is displayed and can be changed. However, if you run the code below you can see the issue that I am having.

```
import os, time 

os.system("clear") #clear screen, if on windows replace with "cls"

globalMap = []
width, height = 10, 10 #width of the map
for x in range(width):
    globalMap.append([])
    for y in range(height):
        globalMap[x].append("0")
blankMap = globalMap
#create two blank 2D lists of width*height (10*10)


def output(interface):
    for x in interface:
        for y in x:
            print(y, end=" ")
        print("")
    #output the argument in a grid, argument must be a 2D list

playerX, playerY = 0, 0

while True: #game loop
    globalMap[playerY][playerX] = "■" #write player position to globalMap

    output(globalMap) #Display the globalMap as a grid
    print("-"*20)
    output(blankMap) #Display the blank map

    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("clear")
    playerX += 1
```

The grid that is outputted on the bottom should remain blank while the grid that is outputted on the top should have a trial of squares animating to the right. I know that somewhere `blankMap` is being set to `globalMap` but I cannot find where.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I know that somewhere `blankMap` is being set to `globalMap` but I cannot find where" - how about **line 11** (counting blank lines as well)

Comment: This is the declaration of  `blankMap` and is only executed once since it is not in a loop or in a function. The problem I am having suggests that  `blankMap` is being set to `globalMap` every time the main loop repeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blankMap = globalMap
```

This line doesn't duplicate `globalMap` but create alias to the same place in memory.

Use `[:]`

```
blankMap = globalMap[:]
```

see: [visualization on PythonTutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=globalMap+%3D+%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%0AblankMap+%3D+globalMap&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=2)

---

EDIT: use `copy.deepcopy` to copy multidimensional list

```
import copy

blankMap = copy.deepcopy(globalMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, lists are objects, and when you do an assignment, the left hand side will point to the right hand side:

```
l1=[]
l2=l1
l1.append(1)
l2                # [1]
id(l1) == id(l2)  # True
```

If you want to make a copy, there are several alternatives:

- Just create a fresh object. Put the pair of loops that creates the blank version into a function and call it twice.
- Check this answer for [deep copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601269/how-to-make-a-completely-unshared-copy-of-a-complicated-list-deep-copy-is-not). For your data structure `copy.deepcopy` will work.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you do:

```
blankMap = globalMap
```

both blankMap and globalMap refer to the same data.  What you really want is a "copy":

```
from copy import deepcopy

...

blankMap = deepcopy(globalMap)
```

Look into "deepcopy" for more info.