# How to not mutate nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

My code:

```
 class World:
    def __init__(self, _map, pos):
        self.orig_map = _map
        self.map = self.orig_map[:]
        self.orig_pos = pos
        self.pos = list(self.orig_pos)
    def reset(self):
        self.map = self.orig_map[:]
        self.pos = list(self.orig_pos)
    def left(self):
        if self.pos[1]>0:
            self.pos[1]-=1
    def right(self):
        if not self.pos[1]+1>=len(self.map[0]):
            self.pos[1]+=1
    def up(self):
        if self.pos[0]>0:
            self.pos[0]-=1
    def down(self):
        if not self.pos[0]+1>=len(self.map):
            self.pos[0]+=1
    def eat(self):
        if self.map[self.pos[0]][self.pos[1]]==1:
            self.map[self.pos[0]][self.pos[1]]=0
            return True
```

What is supposed to happen:

```
>>> w=World([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],(0,0))
>>> w.right()
>>> w.down()
>>> w.eat()
True
>>> w.reset()
>>> w.map
>>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

What happens:

```
>>> w=World([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],(0,0))
>>> w.right()
>>> w.down()
>>> w.eat()
True
>>> w.reset()
>>> w.map
>>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Where it probably goes wrong: `self.map = self.orig_map[:]`

The above would have worked (tried and tested) for a single list, however, it doesn't seem to work for nested lists.

Comment: `deep_copy` it. [See this](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php)

Comment: Did you mean `w.orig_map` in the last step? You could in this case use the `copy` module's [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function.

Comment: @IljaEverilä No, I meant `w.map`. However, at that step, they should be equal (value wise) but be different objects.

Comment: Right, missed the `reset()` call.

Comment: Depending on exactly what `self.orig_map` contains, `deepcopy` may not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601269/how-to-make-a-completely-unshared-copy-of-a-complicated-list-deep-copy-is-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By saying `self.map = self.orig_map[:]` you are indeed making a copy of `self.orig_map`. However, this is a *shallow* copy, and the elements within `self.map` will still be the same objects as the elements within `self.orig_map`.

What you need to do instead is make `self.map` a *deep* copy of `self.orig_map` in your `__init__`. E.g.

```
import copy
...
    self.map = copy.deepcopy(self.orig_map)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `deepcopy`

```
import copy

cop2 = copy.deepcopy(origin)
```

It will recursively copy your object.